# Imputing values into a dataframe based on another dataframe and a condition

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','b','c','d'],'col2':[1,2,3,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col3':['a','x','a','c','b']})
```

I wonder how can I look up on `df1` and make a new column on `df2` and replace values from `col2` in it, for those values that there is no data I shall impute 0, the result should look like the following:

```
  col3  col4
0    a     1
1    x     0
2    a     1
3    c     3
4    b     2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df2['col2'] = df2['col3'].map(df1.set_index('col1')['col2']).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df2)
  col3  col2
0    a     1
1    x     0
2    a     1
3    c     3
4    b     2
```

Or [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), better if need append multiple columns:

```
df = df2.merge(df1.rename(columns={'col1':'col3'}), how='left').fillna(0)
print (df)
  col3  col2
0    a   1.0
1    x   0.0
2    a   1.0
3    c   3.0
4    b   2.0
```